# Disable sticky posts feature in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

I need to create a custom WordPress admin interface for a client. I want to completely disable the sticky post feature from admin area.

I found some posts on the internet that suggest to hide the checkbox using css, but I would really like to disable that feature both from edit and from quick edit screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10676/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-sticky-posts-feature).

The answers here allow you to hide the checkbox using CSS, and to clear the Wordpress option, effectively deleting any record of sticky posts. Not perfect, in my opinion, but a working solution.